# Direct port manipulation to write 40 bits

Tags: digital, shift-register

I have 5 shift register changed in series and want to shift the data quickly. I have learned that the internal shiftOut function is slow and direct port manipulation can speed up the things.

However, I am not sure to write code in the specific way.

The current working code block is:

```
#define SensDataPin 4 
#define SensClockPin 9 
#define SensLatchPin 8 
updateAllShifters()
{
digitalWrite(SensLatchPin, LOW);
shiftOut(SensDataPin,SensClockPin,LSBFIRST,byte_1);
shiftOut(SensDataPin,SensClockPin,LSBFIRST,byte_2);
shiftOut(SensDataPin,SensClockPin,LSBFIRST,byte_3);
shiftOut(SensDataPin,SensClockPin,LSBFIRST,byte_4);
shiftOut(SensDataPin,SensClockPin,LSBFIRST,byte_5);
digitalWrite(SensLatchPin, HIGH);
}
```

As the code shows, I have 5 bytes which are written by independent functions and just before the return statement, these functions call "updateAllShifters()" to mark the changes.

I have followed few tutorials over the internet and have re-written the logic like:

```
#define MSDATAHIGH PORTD |= (1<<PD4)
#define MSDATALOW PORTD &= ~(1<<PD4)
#define MSLATCHHIGH PORTB |= (1<<PB0)
#define MSLATCHLOW PORTB &= ~(1<<PB0)
#define MSCLOCKHIGH PORTB |= (1<<PB1)
#define MSCLOCKLOW PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1)
updateAllShifters()
{
MSLATCHLOW;
for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
{
HOW TO CODE HERE USING THE DEFINED MACROS!
}
MSLATCHHIGH;
```

Edit: Coding example of this (but want a more optimized way):

```
#define MSDATAHIGH PORTD |= (1<<PD4)
#define MSDATALOW PORTD &= ~(1<<PD4)
#define MSLATCHHIGH PORTB |= (1<<PB0)
#define MSLATCHLOW PORTB &= ~(1<<PB0)
#define MSCLOCKHIGH PORTB |= (1<<PB1)
#define MSCLOCKLOW PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1)
updateAllShifters()
{
MSLATCHLOW;
for(byte i=0;i<8;i++)
{
 if(!!(byte_1 & (1 << i)));// LSBFIRST
   {
   MSDATAHIGH;
   }else
   {
   MSDATALOW;
   }
}
 MSCLOCKHIGH;
 MSCLOCKLOW;
//DO ABOVE FOR ALL REMAINING 4 BYTES
MSLATCHHIGH;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using SPI?

Comment: I have few SPI ADC which have forced SPI bus down to 1 Mhz. I understand that the shiftout works at 14Khz which is too slow. I just want to optimize it to maximum possible level.

Answer (score 2):

> I have few SPI ADC which have forced SPI bus down to 1 Mhz. I understand that the shiftout works at 14Khz which is too slow.

You can change the SPI speed at any time. Once the device is selected (Slave Select asserted) then reconfigure the SPI bus for high speed operation.

eg.

```
SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);
```

SPI is definitely the fastest way you can communicate with a shift register.